# Jetpack Carousel not working

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, jetpack

I'm trying to add Jetpack's Carousel plugin to a Wordpress website, however, even when activated, my images are still just opening as a standard link.

I've deactivated all my other plugins and tried the Carousel, but there was no change. I've also changed the JQuery link in the header to link to Google's server, instead of the natively hosted version. Again, no change. It's wrecking my head trying to get this to work. All out of ideas at this stage.

The site is http://www.theemeraldexiles.com and in particular I want the Carousel to work with this Tiled Gallery on this page: http://theemeraldexiles.com/exile-profile-aiden-mcgeady/

Anyone any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong in your site, because I compare with my site and I found some differences between carousel options.

Did you set the options in wp-admin/options-media.php ?

Does your theme has some custom gallery functionalities?

Links can help you:

http://jetpack.me/2012/07/13/jetpack-1-5-with-carousel/

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/jetpack-carousel-not-working

Comment: Hi @jpussacq, thanks for your reply. How/Where would I find whether my theme has custom gallery functionalities? Haven't touch anything in options-media.php.